# $location.search being changed automatically, cannot manually set either

Tags: angularjs

**Edit:** The reset/TypeError was due to not specifying `reloadOnSearch: false` in the route. For the pagination trying to redirect the page to the default value (`1`), telling the page to load results in a `$timeout` solved this.

I'm having a rather annoying error in angularJS at the moment.

I'm trying to get & set a specific search parameter:

```
    var searchParams = $location.search();
    $scope.limit = searchParams.limit > 0 ? searchParams.limit : 10;
    $scope.currentPage = searchParams.page > 0 ? searchParams.page : 1;
```

This gets the parameter fine, however if I load the page with any parameters except the defaults there (10 and 1), it will automatically reload (Triggering the controller twice) using the defaults.

Additionally, when I set the search query myself:

```
    $scope.changePage = function() {
        $location.search('page', $scope.currentPage);
        getUsers();
    };
```

It is causing the following `TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined` error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at resolveElementClasses (http://localhost:8080/site/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:480:22)
    at http://localhost:8080/site/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:1028:27
    at http://localhost:8080/site/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js:469:22
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8080/site/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13324:36)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/site/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13540:24)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/site/bower_components/angular/angular.js:21697:23)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:8080/site/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2986:21)
  (anonymous function)  angular.js:10683
  (anonymous function)  angular.js:7858
  Scope.$digest angular.js:13326
  Scope.$apply  angular.js:13540
  (anonymous function)  angular.js:21697
  eventHandler  angular.js:2986
```

Here's the full controller - it loads users with pagination - in theory nothing complicated:

```
app.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'User', function ($scope, $location, User) {
    // Get from URL if present, else set defaults
    var searchParams = $location.search();
    $scope.limit = searchParams.limit > 0 ? searchParams.limit : 10;
    $scope.currentPage = searchParams.page > 0 ? searchParams.page : 1;

    var getUsers = function() {
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.users = null;
        User.one().get({
            'limit': $scope.limit,
            'offset': ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.limit
        }).then(function(resp) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.users = resp.data;
            $scope.users_count = resp._meta.total_count;
        });
    };

    getUsers();

    $scope.changePage = function() {
        $location.search('page', $scope.currentPage);
        getUsers();
    };
}]);
```

I can't see anything wrong here, but maybe I'm missing something.

- Controller triggers twice if manually going to the route with a URL search param (eg `http:/site/users?page=2` will trigger, then instantly reload with `http://site/users?page=1`)
- Setting the search param when changing page causes a `TypeError`.

Comment: Would your controller be registered twice by any chance ? Once in routes, once on viewer ? This could possibly account for your first issue at least

Comment: Nope, only ever referenced once. It only ever triggers twice if `page` is set to anything other than `1`.